# merge changes of two repositores with unrelated histories

Tags: git

I created a new repository (New) with a copy of the files of my (main) repository. I did this because I didn't want to share the whole repository history with some new developers, as it contains very sensitive data.

My idea was to give this brand new repository with the current state of the files to the new developers but with an empty history, ask them to work there, and then merge from the (new) repository to my original, (main) repository.

I would need to also make the other way, I would need to merge changes from my (main) repository to the (new).

My first attempt was to add the (new) repo as a remote on the folder where I have the main repository, and then merge to the (main) with:

```
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories evisa_clone/master
```

However, this causes all files that have been changed on the (main) repository to be treated as conflicts, even when the files were not modified on the (new) repository, a lot of files has `both added` on the `git status` screen.

What alternative do I've?

Comment: I've never attempted anything like this, but it is going to get ugly.  Git wasn't really designed to make it easy to commit, merge, etc. from two branches across different repositories.  Maybe try to think of a way to protect your sensitive information from other users using a single repo, e.g. using a branch which no one else can pull.

Comment: It's possible to create branch with permissions to pull on gitlab / github? I though permissions are only to push.

Comment: Or maybe create a private fork to which only you would have access.  You would keep the fork up to date yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking to accept changes to a repository without giving the other people the whole history but they can use the current state of the files. This is simply done with a separate clone but only cloning with `depth=1`

### Steps

- `git clone <repo> --depth=1 --branch=<dev or whatever>`
- The other developers(TODs) will work on this new clone that will not
  have any of the older history but have a valid SHA id that correlates
  with your repository.
- TODs should fork off of this new repository and create branches for
  all of their work.
- To pull in their work, they'll essentially do Pull Requests of their
  branches to the depth=1 branch.
- For them to get updates to the repository, you need to keep the
  original depth=1 repo branch up to date w/ the original repository
  and they will just continue their work: fetching, branching,
  commiting, PRing

### Alternative

- `git clone <repo> --depth=1 --branch=<dev or whatever>`
- You treat this new repository as the one to work off.

  - History can be important but if its not needed, its not needed.